# Java: deleting text in an csv which starts with --

Tags: java, parsing, csv, match

I am loading a csv file and kept alive without closing `BufferReader`. Now I want to delete all lines which starts  with -- and save that csv in a temp CSV. Anybody have an idea how I can do this find only c# code.
I tried to fix with regular expression but I failed.
An example of the csv:

```
-- DDL- "T453453   "."BMG"
-- DDL- "T423342   "."BMG234"

CREATE TABLE "T453453   "."BMG"  

-- DDL- "T42234234   "."BMG236"
```

So it works but i have the last problem how i can add \n (Newline) cause if i debug this code i get the text in one line.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class CsV {
    public static String Read() throws IOException{
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C://Users//myd//Desktop//BW//BWFormated.csv")));
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inputFile = new File("C://Users//myd//Desktop//BW//BWtest.csv");
        File tempFile = new File("C://Users//myd//Desktop//BW//BWFormated.csv");


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String lineToRemove = "--";
        String currentLine;

        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
            if(trimmedLine.startsWith(lineToRemove)) continue;
            writer.write(currentLine);
        }
        writer.close();
        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        System.out.println(Read());

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you have try any thing? You should try and when you have a problem you will ask here.

Comment: That doesn't even remotely look like a CSV file, by the way.

Comment: yes i know but it must be an csv... it is an converted .sql file  after delete the -- (comments) i have to parse the other lines. so the final result gonna look like this T453453;BMG. Im new @ Java and it is hard for me :(

Comment: open file, find and replace "--" chars with "", save result in file

Comment: i tried: writer.write("\n" + currentLine)                               but it doenst work :/

Comment: Check the edit in my answer, how to add new lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check each line, if it begins with `--` using [String.startsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method.

If so, read the next line and if the line has content you want to make other things with, you can put it into a list. Maybe like this:

```
String line;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(line.startsWith("--"))
        continue;
    list.add(line);
}

for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    line = list.get(i);
    // use regular expressions to extract the data you want to convert into CSV format
}
```

**Hint:** I didn't check my syntax, so it could be, that it won't be compiled ;-)

Use [the Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for regular expressions and maybe [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) will help you.

Good luck!

**EDIT**

Extend your while-loop to the following, which allows you to add new lines, too:

```
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
    if(trimmedLine.startsWith(lineToRemove))
        continue;
    writer.write(currentLine);
    writer.newLine(); // Writes a line separator.
}
```

[Read the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) to the `newLine()` method.